# How do I get the full path of an asset?

Tags: plugin-development, assets

I've written a simple plugin that attaches to the onSaveEntry event. I'd like to access the image, extract the colours from the image using https://github.com/brianmcdo/ImagePalette and then save these colours to a field. I've managed to access the entry, but can't seem to find how to get the path and filename of the image?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it with the `getURL()` method?

Something like this should work (NB! have not tested the code myself):

```
$image = $entry->image->first();
if ($image) {
    $url = $image->getUrl();
}
```

Comment: He's asking about the path, not the URL